# How can you find the maximum area of a triangle inscribed in a circle

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the maximum possible area of a right triangle ABC that has vertex A at the point (1,0), vertex B somewhereon the top half of the unit circle, and vertexC on the x-axis, vertically below vertex B.
[image]

I can't figure out where to start. I know the distance from the origin to C is x and the height of B is y. I can't figure out what the secant line equation is for the line between the points A and B. I also know the distance between C and A is 1-x.

Can someone please help me get started. I know it's an optimization problem, but I just can't figure out how to get

Comment: You might find it easier to use the angle $AOB$ as the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the secant equation.  The area of the triangle is $\frac 12$ base height.  The base is $1-x$ as you say.  The height is $y$, but you need to express that in terms of $x$.  Then you will have area=$f(x)$ and you can differentiate, set the derivative to zero,...  It should be clear that the $x$ that maximizes the triangle area will be negative, as when it is positive decreasing it  increases both the base and the height.

Comment: Actually, $-1\le x\le1$, not $x$ negative

Comment: @DaleM:  I meant that the $x$ that maximizes the area will be negative, because the area of a triangle with $x$ positive will be less than the one with $x=0$.  I think it is useful to think of easy checks that the answer must satisfy-it catches some errors.

Comment: You could maximise the square of the area, which would avoid expressions with square roots until the end.

Comment: oh shoot, and y = square root of (1-x^2). I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use as variable the arc $AB=\theta$. You search the max of the function:
$$
y=\dfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos \theta)\sin \theta
$$
the derivative is
$$
y'=-\dfrac{1}{2}(2\cos^2 \theta - \cos \theta -1)
$$
so the stationary points in your interval are $\cos \theta=0$ (min) and $\cos -\dfrac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \theta = \dfrac{2 \pi}{3}$ (Max).